# Remove blank cells from CSV file with python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a text file that I am converting to **csv** using python. The text file has columns that are set using several spaces. My code strips the line, converts 2 spaces in a row to commas, and then splits the lines again. When I do this, the columns don't line up because there are some columns that have more blank spaces than others. How can I add something to my code that will remove the blank cells in my **csv** file?

I have tried converting the csv file to a *pandas database*, but when I run

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('old.Csv')

delim_whitespace=True

df.to_csv("New.Csv", index=False)
```

it returns an error `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 40 fields in line 10, saw 42`

The code that is stripping the lines and splitting them is

```py
import csv

txtfile = r"Old.txt"
csvfile = r"Old.Csv"

with open(txtfile, 'r') as infile, open(csvfile, 'w', newline='') as outfile:    
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in infile)
    replace = (line.replace("  ", ",") for line in stripped if line)
    lines = (line.split(",") for line in replace if infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(lines)
```

Comment: Can you paste more information on your data ? For instance, do you have blanc lines or columns ? How is your data separated?

Comment: The data in the original text file is separated with multiple spaces. When the description text ends, spaces are populated to justify the numbers in the first numerical column ( a shorter description will add more spaces)

Comment: @TBrownell add skiprow=[1] to the below code , it should work.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to declare column names beforehand, so as to force pandas to data with different number of columns. Something like this should work :

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfilepath', names = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

You will have to adapt separator and column names / number of columns yourself.

Comment: declaring column names will not change the data though, correct? I would still have blank spaces in some of the cells and the data would not line up, it would just restrict the number of columns

Answer (score 0):

(edited)below code should work for your text file:

```
   a               b  c  d  e
=============================
1  qwerty          3  4  5  6
2  ewer            e  r  y  i               
3  asdfghjkutrehg  c  v  b  n
```

you can try:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_fwf('textfile.txt', delimiter='  ', header=0, skiprows=[1])
df.to_csv("New.csv", index=False)
print(df)  

   Unnamed: 0               a  b  c  d  e
0           1          qwerty  3  4  5  6
1           2            ewer  e  r  y  i
2           3  asdfghjkutrehg  c  v  b  n
```